# How exactly am I supposed to use the ID3DXFont interface? (Direct3D 11, c++)

Tags: c++, direct3d11

I understand that Microsoft prefers people to use Direct2D and DirectWrite to render text in a game, but using these APIs in a Direct3D11 can be a bit tedious. So i want to use the ID3DXFont interface to render text but the problem is that i don't know how to use it.

I tried googling for a tutorial on how to use the interface but i couldn't really find any.

Anyway, down below is my attempt at implementing the interface.

```
void Create_Font_Device()
{
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS presentation;
IDirect3D9 * FontDeviceDesc = NULL;
IDirect3DDevice9 * FontDevice = NULL;

ZeroMemory(&presentation, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));
presentation.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
presentation.Windowed = TRUE;

FontDeviceDesc = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

FontDeviceDesc->CreateDevice(
            D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
            D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
            MainWindow,
            D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
            &presentation,
            &FontDevice
            );

D3DXCreateFont(
        FontDevice,
        20,
        20,
        1,
        false,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,
        OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS,
        ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
        NULL,
        L"Arial",
        &Font
        );
}


/* The Draw_Text() function is called in my game loop */


void Draw_Text()
{
RECT WindowCoordinates;

WindowCoordinates.left = 200;
WindowCoordinates.right = 200;
WindowCoordinates.top = 200;
WindowCoordinates.bottom = 200;

Font->DrawText(
            NULL,
            L"FPS: ",
            5,
            &WindowCoordinates,
            DT_TOP,
            D3DCOLOR_XRGB(1, 1, 255)
            );

}
```

This code is not enough to actually write any text onto the screen, what exactly am i missing here? How am i supposed to implement the ID3DXFont interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no version of D3DXFont that works for Direct3D 11. D3DX11 does not have a font API because as you note the general expectation is you'd use Direct2D/DirectWrite.

> All version of D3DX are deprecated including D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)

For simple text rendering on Direct3D 11, the `SpriteFont` class in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is very easy to use. See the [Drawing text](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Drawing-text) tutorial.

```
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont> font(new SpriteFont(device, L"myfile.spritefont"));
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> spriteBatch(new SpriteBatch(context));

spriteBatch->Begin();

font->DrawString(spriteBatch.get(), L"FPS: ", XMFLOAT2(200,200));

spriteBatch->End();
```

> `SpriteFont` is a simple bitmap-captured font, which works very well for smaller fonts like the ASCII or extended ASCII character set. It is not particularly suited to rendering large character font languages like Japanese, Korean, or Chinese or for alternative writing systems like Arabic. In these cases, Direct2D/DirectWrite really is the best way to go.

Comment: I have followed every instruction that was given in the link that you gave. But everytime I #include the header file SpriteFont.h or the SpriteBatch.h, i get compiler errors that say there is ambiguous calls to overloaded functions in the "DirectXMathMatrix.inl"......... But this only happens when i include SpriteFont.h.... what can i do to fix this, i never really got an error like this..

Comment: Make sure you are NOT trying to use both ``xnamath.h`` and ``directxmath.h`` at the same time. ``SpriteFont.h`` and ``SpriteBatch.h`` include ``DirectXMath.h``

Comment: Yes, you are right about `xnamath.h`, but now i have another problem. I keep getting the compiler errors that says there is a `missing type specifier - int assumed` , `syntax error: missing ',' before '*'`, and `syntax error: identifier 'DXGI_RGBA'` and these errors are in the file `dxgi1_2.h`....i have a feeling that something could be wrong with the order of my header files.. but i'm not sure.. what could be the problem? here are the headers that i used in the following order `Windows.h, dinput.h, d3d11.h, d3dx11async.h, dwrite.h, dxgi.h, d2d1.h, sstream.h, simplemath.h, spritefont.h`

Comment: If you are using VS 2012 or later, make sure you have the headers in the proper include order for the legacy DirectX SDK or better yet, remove all use of the legacy DirectX SDK from your project. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)